# When deleting a theme, are the theme customizer settings also deleted from the database?

Tags: theme-customizer

So if I deleted a theme, then changed my mind later and decided to install the same theme again, would the customizer settings I had configured be deleted, or would they be saved so I still have them when I re-install the theme?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, your settings will not be deleted. They will be available next time you install the theme.

Long answer: There are 2 ways a theme can store its settings in the database: `options` and `theme_mods`. If they use options, then inside the `wp_option` table in the database there will probably be an option called `{$theme-name}` or `{$theme-name}_options` etc. It's up to the theme author what option name they choose.
If they use `theme_mods`, inside the `wp_options` table in your database there will be a `theme_mods_{$theme-name}` entry containing all the options.

When a theme gets deactivated these options are not deleted by default, and WordPress keeps them there for future use.

There *is* a way for themes to delete their options on deactivation (see the [`switch_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/switch_theme) action) but it's rarely used and there's no reason any theme author would use it to delete the theme settings on deactivation - unless it's a custom use-case.